# Use nginx as a reverse proxy to point to a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a server written in nodejs, located in /root/website/src which listens on port 8080. This does work when you visit the site with the port attached to the ip.
However, I can’t seem to configure nginx to point from ports 80 and 443 to 8080 in order for it to work.
My config for nginx is

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you share the logs from nginx? What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

NGINX's port is configured through the [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive inside a [`server`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) context.

The configuration below should enable redirection of all `http` requests to the `443` port, which is the default for `https` connections.

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 443;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
  }
}
```